# PHP Cross-Origin-Request blocked

Tags: php, http, header, cors

I have a PHP-script which takes a POST-variable from a request, does something with it (in this case it's an memcached request for the specific key) and sends it back via JSON.

The complicated part is that I don't host this script on the same Server as I do with the script doing the request. So I tried to use CORS. My browser tells me that I haven't set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin-Header, but I did as you can see. So I guess that I set it wrong. But I haven't really dealt with headers in PHP so I have really no clue what do do. I already searched (also on Stackoverflow) but all I found is that I have to set this header, what I did...

Of ourse the memcache-part isn't really interesting for solving the problem but I thought it would be better to let you guys take a look at the complete code, so here you go:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * ");
$key = $_POST["key"];
$json = "";
if($key != "")
{

    define('MEMCACHED_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
    define('MEMCACHED_PORT', '11211');
    $memcache = new Memcache;
    $memcache->connect(MEMCACHED_HOST, MEMCACHED_PORT);

    $value = memcache->get($key);

    $json_array = array("status" => "done" , "key" => $key, "value" => $value);
    $json = json_encode($json_array);
}
else
{
    $json_array = array("status" => "empty");
    $json = json_encode($json_array);

}
echo $json;
?>
```

Comment: You have to set that header on the server where your POST variables originally came from.

Comment: It looks like you have correctly set the header to allow all hosts. What does the script retrieving this JSON look like?

Comment: Security note about `$key` -  you should check that input against a list of acceptable values. Otherwise, it would be possible for a client to query any accessible value out of your memcached by guessing at the key.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski the client is just a simple Javascript (JQuery) AJAX handler printing out the response. That already worked find with just sending back the value of key, but when I processed it this error occured.

Comment: Of course this is just a script for testing. I will check the variables before using them in the real application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting some lines into the Apache .conf file did it. If someone is interested, these lines can be found [here](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled). I still don't know why it didn't worked with the headers in PHP. Maybe I did something wrong with the client. But it's working now :)